# MS Access Database query file path criteria in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, file-io

I have an MS Access database that has Full paths to files in a table. We are moving all the file to a different location. I need to update the database. I'm using C# to do this. When I search for the file path stored in access it searches for 'K:\PDFFiles\myPDF.pdf' instead of 'K:\PDFFiles\myPDF.pdf' and does not find a match. So, my question is how do I query the access database for the correct file name instead of the escaped file name?

Thanks

Comment: Could the file extension be mdf instead of pdf?

Comment: 'K:\PDFFiles\myPDF.pdf' instead of 'K:\PDFFiles\myPDF.pdf' <--- They look the same to me.  Please clarify.

Comment: Are these paths stored in a normal text field or in an OLE link field? If the former, just run an UPDATE query to parse out the original and convert it to the new. If the latter, you've got a much bigger problem, and might want to try SUBST to fake the old drive letter and JUNCTION to create virtual folders that are somewhat like UNIX symbolic links. This will make the new location look like the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
@"K:\PDFFiles\myPDF.pdf"
```

or

```
"K:\\PDFFiles\\myPDF.pdf"
```

Does your select statement quote the path, something like this (note the single quotes around the parameter):

```
string sql = string.Format("select * from MyTable where MyPathField = '{0}'", "K:\\PDFFiles\\myPDF.pdf");
```

Comment: I have tried these what gets put in the parameter I send to the query is "K:\\PDFFiles\\myPDF.pdf" and it doesn't find a match.